# How aware are the Phineas and Ferb characters that they're in a TV show?

Tags: fourth-wall, phineas-and-ferb

*Phineas & Ferb* characters are shown breaking the 4th wall with surprising regularity... at least, that I've encountered in watching random episodes on YouTube. For instance, in *Meapless in Seattle*, *Phineas's Birthday - Clip-O-Rama!*, *Mission Marvel*, and *Make Play*, the 4th wall is broken at least once.

- In *Meapless in Seattle*, when Dr. Doofenshmirtz and Meap are falling, they have a conversation about the commercial break.
- In *Phineas's Birthday - Clip-O-Rama!*, Phineas and other characters make several references to 'a clip show'.
- In *Mission Marvel*, Dr. Doofenshmirtz makes a remark about 'I thought that this was going to be a special extended episode'.
- In *Make Play*, Carl says 'it's a cartoon', and then Major Monogram yells at him not to break the 4th wall.

And I also recall some episode where Candace asks Phineas something about 'don't you have a catchprase to say now' and then Phineas delivers a variation of the 'Where's Perry?' line.

There are other examples; these are just a few. (I can find some more if necessary.)

**Given that they break the 4th wall fairly often, how aware are they that they are just characters in a TV show?**

Answer (score 13):

**They are pretty aware of it.**

The fourth wall is broken many times in Phineas and Ferb.
[Here](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/BreakingTheFourthWall/PhineasAndFerb) is a list with scenes and episodes and quotes when they did it.

Here are some of the best ones that really show it:

In "Agent Doof"

> when everyone gets turned into babies except Candace, Candace says it had "better wear off by the **next episode**."

In "Wizard of Odd"

> Phineas actually **lifts the screen** like a curtain and **talks to the audience** from behind it.

In "Phineas and Ferb Save Summer"

> in reaction to an outburst from Phineas, Buford says "This must be a **special episode**, he's yelling at his sister again."

In "A Real Boy"

> when comparing the situation with Vanessa to a cheesy sitcom, both Perry and Doof **stare directly into the camera**.

In "Summer Belongs to You"

> Linda: It sure would be helpful if they could just make the days a little longer.
>   [A "ding" noise signaling an idea is heard as the bottom half of the screen is covered with an "advertisement" reading "You're Watching Television!"]
>   Phineas: Hey! Do you mind? We've kinda got a visual gag going on here!
>   [Advertisement disappears, revealing the "ding" was actually from Ferb with a triangle.]
>   Phineas: Thank you!

In "The Musical Episode"

> The kids who take the poster from the wall (just like in the pilot) are stopped by Buford.
>   Buford: If any one's gonna ride this roller coaster, it's gonna be me. Not one of you lousy **extras**.

Comment: But what does this answer add to the examples from the question other than just extending the list by *more* of the same examples? The question seems to be asking for some inherent awareness of their nature as TV characters beyond just more examples of the same practice of breaking the 4th wall. Otherwise it wouldn't have presented examples itself.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson because some of those examples have a really obvious message that it's a TV show. Like the ones where Candice and Buford mention *next* and *special episodes*. Similar with *extras*.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson for the "how aware are they" question a list is demonstration that they are _very_ aware as it is a recurring theme.

Comment: A better method might be to determine the percentage of episodes where the 4th wall is broken.  If it's every episode, then one could say with certainty that they are perfectly aware of it. But if there are only the 10 episodes already listed, then 10/222 is under 5%, and would suggest that they're not very aware, just rarely or occasionally aware.